# Easy way to change controller and view name without messing up links?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there an easy way to rename controllers and views without messing up links?
Lets say

Index() 
redirect (~/User/Index);

now I'm changing the Index view name to Details, but that will mess up everything. So is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Why? `Url.Action` would still be fine, you'll need to update explicit routes anyway... Consider specifying what "everything" you mean.

Comment: Do you know about Routing, if you don't learn here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx